# Import iTunes playlists to Spotify

Tags: itunes, spotify

I'd like to migrate from Apple Music to Spotify because:

1. iTunes still can't upload more than ~30 seconds of a custom song / music file to iCloud Music Library. Spotify can't upload to a cloud but can upload to other devices (by using the playlist download feature) and actually does so for the entire song.
2. Apple Music doesn't integrate with anything properly or at all, last.fm most notably where the iOS app has been massively duplicating Apple Music scrobbles for over a year with no end in sight. Spotify has account-level integration.
3. Apple Music still doesn't have a web player.

However, I have 16 playlists with 1,781 songs spread over them and, according to https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Windows/Importing-iTunes-playlists/td-p/4392200, Spotify removed the function to import playlists from iTunes around February 2018 to improve it (WTF).

Is there any way around this?

I have tried:

1. Using Spotify version 1.0.73.345 (obtained from https://www.filehorse.com/download-spotify/33808/ - digital signature verified) but it (1) imported from the really old file `iTunes Music Library.xml` and didn't recognise the new, current file `iTunes Library.xml`.
2. Exporting the playlists from iTunes (tab-delimited TXT files), using Excel to convert those to comma-delimited CSV files, and using [Soundiiz](https://soundiiz.com/)'s free plan to convert and migrate those to my Spotify account but it matches against Spotify's database, not the local files, so there's a load of obscure songs missing.
3. Using [TuneMyMusic](https://www.tunemymusic.com/XML-to-Spotify.php) but it doesn't recognise playlists, only the library.
4. Looking into using [iTunes2Spotify](http://itunes2spotify.mrupp.ch/) but I don't trust it and an unlimited version isn't free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wondered if Spotify was simply looking for a file named `iTunes Music Library.xml` so I deleted the old one and renamed the new one then, using the old version, I was able to import the iTunes playlists into Spotify.

After I uninstalled the old version and installed the new version, I'm having difficulty getting the local files to re-add but the playlists list **all** of the songs (just greyed out) so it should be able to map them once I get them re-added. I'll report back.

**Edit: 2018/12/07 18:48:**

So, even though the above did work, there was a major problem: it entirely referenced local files which rendered the web player entirely useless.

So, I ended up using Soundiiz and, using its error reports of songs that couldn't be found, manually filling in the gaps.

Comment: `iTunes Music Library.xml` is a defunct format, no longer used by iTunes itself [it uses the .itl instead] but can be used to support other apps which still rely on it. As such iTunes treats it as 'write only' - make sure it's enabled in Prefs > Advanced >  Share iTunes XML with other apps

Answer (score 0):

My name is Nir, I'm from TuneMyMusic team.

by
"doesn't recognise playlists, only the library".
Do you mean that the songs are not separated to playlists correctly?

Please note - There is an option to separate to playlists by the containing folder name - See here: [Folder name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53Z6a.jpg).

If that isn't what you want - Please contact out support (support@tunemymusic.com), attach your iTunes file